# How to format different templates for angular 2 blog posts?

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I want to create a blog with angular 2. I am struggling to find the answer to my question.

My problem is I want each blog post template to be different because I'll have a different format for each post with different images, snippets and blocks of text so reading from a JSON object won't be sufficient.

For example if I was just creating a normal static website I would just create each blog post with its own custom HTML page and have the flexibility to format the page in any way.

But in angular to I need to stick with the one template, how can I have a different template for each post without creating a new component for each new post?

Advice needed, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use innerHTML to display field as HTML. Assuming you have a `BlogPostComponent` and a property `content` which is HTML. Then in your template, you can do something like this:

```
<h1>{{ title }}</h1>
<div [innerHTML]="content"></div>
```